# ASP.net image.imageurl not showing anything

Tags: asp.net

i have a server image control the id is Picoftheday and i was trying to generate a url for that image control..
here is my image url generating code.....

```
private string PicID()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Connection dbconn = new Connection();
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select top(1) picture_ID from t_picture order by Picture_UploadDate desc";
        ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
        cmd.Connection = dbconn.DBConnection;
        ad.Fill(dt);
        string value = null;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            value = dr[0].ToString();

        }
        string url = Server.MapPath("..\\ArchievedPic\\Thumbnail\\");
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@url, "" + value + ".*");
       // string url = files[0].ToString();
        string money = files[0].ToString();
        return money;
    }
```

on page load ....

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Picoftheday.ImageUrl = PicID();
    }
```

can anyone help please..

Answer (score 1):

MapPath needs a tilde that represents the root directory of the asp application:

```
string url = Server.MapPath("~\\ArchievedPic\\Thumbnail\\");
```